# "Error: resolver or addr is not configured for ENS name ethers" in dApp with Etherjs

Tags: react, goerli

I am currently struggling to figure out this error:

```
Error: resolver or addr is not configured for ENS name
```

It points to the function that I've listed here:

```
//Create A New Contract
  async function newContract() {
    const beneficiary = document.getElementById("beneficiary").value;
    const arbiter = document.getElementById("arbiter").value;
    const value = ethers.utils.parseEther(
      document.getElementById("wei").value,
      "ether"
    );

    try {
      const tx = await createNewContract(signer, arbiter, beneficiary, value);
      await tx.wait();
      setMessage("Contract Is Created");
      setMessageType("success");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("err new contract", err);
      setMessage("Error: Transaction couldn't be deployed.");
      setMessageType("error");
    }

    // List of personal escrows and escrows to approve
    const escrowsList = await getListContracts(signer);
    setEscrows(escrowsList);

    const escrowsListToApprove = await getContractsToApprove(signer);
    setEscrowsToApprove(escrowsListToApprove);
  }
```

The purpose of the function is to create a new contract for an escrow dapp I am building for a bootcamp. The smart contract is deployed on Goerli and has passed all the tests.

The function `createNewContract()` is from the smart contract, am I passing the wrong arguments into that function? Should declare a signer variable before the try catch statement?

Does anyone know how to solve this error?